# Zooming to layer with page definition query set in ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, data-driven-pages

I have data driven pages enabled on a mxd, with a **[page definition query](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s90000003p000000)** set on one of the layers to only show features that match the current index feature. This layer looks like this:

[image: Full layer]

After enabling the page definition query, right clicking on the layer and clicking `Zoom to Layer` yields this:

[image: Using the UI to zoom to layer]

I would like to perform this function in ArcPy. Setting the data frame's extent to the extent of the layer using the `getExtent()` method zooms to the extent of the entire layer:

[image: Arcpy method]

This method does not honour the extent of the page definition query. I cannot use the `zoomToSelectedFeatures()` method of the data frame because nothing is actually selected; similarly I cannot use the layer's `getSelectedExtent()` method. The only workaround I see is updating a normal definition query on the layer from ArcPy and then getting the extent.

Is there a way to use the UI's `Zoom to Layer` method from ArcPy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in your Question, the way that I do this is by "updating a normal definition query on the layer from arcpy" and then using getSelectedExtent().

Some code using a Queensland (Australia) Lot on Plan example:

```
import arcpy

inputMap = r"C:\temp\test.mxd"
inputLotNo = "1"
inputPlanNo = "RP1"

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(inputMap)
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"Main Map")[0]
subjectLotLayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"Subject Lot",df)[0]

where_clause = "LOT = '" + inputLotNo + "' AND PLAN = '" + inputPlanNo + "'"
subjectLotLayer.definitionQuery = where_clause
df.extent = subjectLotLayer.getSelectedExtent(False)
```

If you must do this using *page definition queries* then I suspect that you will need to work through the support system and/or ArcGIS Ideas to try and achieve that.

Comment: This is what I ended up using, quite successfully, across multiple projects and dozens of scripts.